# adding NSInteger object to NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsinteger

I have an NSMutableArray

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

NSMutableArray *reponses;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *reponses;

@end
```

and i'm trying to add in my array NSInteger object:

```
@synthesize reponses;



NSInteger val2 = [indexPath row];
[reponses addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:val2]];
NSLog(@"the array is %@ and the value is %i",reponses, val2);
```

it won't work the object was not added to the array, this is what console shows:

```
the array is (null) and the value is 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not initializing your array, so it's still `nil` when you're trying to add to it.

```
self.responses = [NSMutableArray array];
//now you can add to it.
```

Answer (score 9):

@Omz: is right. Make sure you have the array allocated and initialized. Please check the following code

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSInteger num = 7;
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:num];
[ar addObject:number];
NSLog(@"Array %@",array);
```

I have checked this and it works.
If `array` is no longer needed make sure you `release` it.

Comment: for new folks (me), to convert NSNumber back to NSInteger (when retrieving information from the array), 'NSInteger num = [number integerValue];'  (thank you 7KV7)

Answer (score 2):

You have not initialized the responses array. In your code, may be viewDidLoad, do:

```
reponses = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Then add the object to your array.

```
NSInteger val2 = [indexPath row];
[self.reponses addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:val2]];
```

That should work.